# Combining several XSD in one

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have 5 XSD files, one is the "main one" (I said main one because here is where I want to add the rest of schema files), called catalogo.xsd and the rest of them are secondaries(dataset.xsd,imagenes.xsd,propietario.xsd,identificacion.xsd). In catalogo.xsd I want to import the namespace of one of this files, for instance, propietario.xsd. So I import it in catalogo.xsd writing this line of code:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/catalogo" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/catalogo" elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xsd:import namespace = "http://www.example.org/propietario" schemaLocation = "propietario.xsd"/>
```

The file propietario.xsd is something like this:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/propietario" xmlns:prop="http://www.example.org/propietario" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:element name="tPropietario">
<xsd:complexType>
 whatever code here
 </xsd:complexType>
```

But in catalogo, when I want to add an element of type = `prop:tPropietario`, eclipse gives me an error saying that `prop:` prefix is not define. I don't understand how to add it properly, the path of the `schemaLocation` its fine, and the namespace uri as well. I don't know if I explain it clear, but that's my problem.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This namespace declaration,

```
xmlns:prop="http://www.example.org/propietario"
```

will set `prop` as a namespace prefix for the `http://www.example.org/propietario` namespace.  Add it to any element at or above its use in any XML file, including the XSD, in which you wish to refer to this namespace as `prop`.  For an XSD, namespace declarations are often grouped together on the `xsd:schema` root element.